Snowflake: load big JSON file into table
I am trying to load this big JSON file (sample can be seen below) into one of my tables in Snowflake. I tried creating an internal stage "TEST" with Snowsight and manually importing the file into the internal stage. I then ran the following command from my internal stage:
COPY INTO TEST
  FROM (
          SELECT $1
           FROM @TEST
       )
  FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = 'JSON');

The above loaded the file with no errors however when I run a SELECT * FROM TEST to check the content of the table TEST I see the file has not been imported properly as probably it exceeds the 16MB limit of the variant data type column ("value too large" as seen in screenshot):

A sample of the file I am trying to upload can be seen below (the "results" keys in the original file is much bigger than the one seen below). Any ideas / suggestions how I should go about importing this file into a table in Snowflake?
{
    "payload": {
        "run_details": {
            "run_id": "abc",
            "run_date": "2024-06-26 03:56:58"
        },
        "connections": {
            "source": {
                "type": "oracle",
                "host": "abc",
                "database": "abc",
                "table_name": "table1"
            },
            "target": {
                "type": "snowflake",
                "database": "abc",
                "schema": "abc",
                "table_name": "table2"
            }
        },
        "Keys": [
            "ACCOUNTING_ID",
            "SEQ"
        ],
        "Comparison_Columns": [
            "ACCOUNTING_YEAR",
            "ACCOUNTING_PERIOD",
            "CURR_AMOUNT",
            "ROWVERSION"
        ],
        "results": [
            {
                "Sign": "-",
                "keys": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_ID": "abc",
                    "SEQ": "1"
                },
                "columns": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_YEAR": null,
                    "ACCOUNTING_PERIOD": null,
                    "CURR_AMOUNT": "11111",
                    "ROWVERSION": "2024-06-24 22:41:11.000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "Sign": "+",
                "keys": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_ID": "111111",
                    "SEQ": "1"
                },
                "columns": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_YEAR": null,
                    "ACCOUNTING_PERIOD": null,
                    "CURR_AMOUNT": "11111.000",
                    "ROWVERSION": "2024-06-25 22:41:16.000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "Sign": "-",
                "keys": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_ID": "abc",
                    "SEQ": "2"
                },
                "columns": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_YEAR": null,
                    "ACCOUNTING_PERIOD": null,
                    "CURR_AMOUNT": "731.2600000",
                    "ROWVERSION": "2024-06-24 22:41:11.000000"
                }
            },
            {
                "Sign": "+",
                "keys": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_ID": "1111111",
                    "SEQ": "2"
                },
                "columns": {
                    "ACCOUNTING_YEAR": null,
                    "ACCOUNTING_PERIOD": null,
                    "CURR_AMOUNT": "700000.00000",
                    "ROWVERSION": "2024-06-25 22:41:16.000000"
                }
            }
            
}


"Value too large" in this case is just a display problem. If data loaded without errors, data should be fine - it's just that Snowsight doesn't want to show an object that large.
For example, this looks fine:
select [array_agg(c_name)]
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer


But this is too large (to display):
select [array_agg(c_name), array_agg(c_name)]
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.customer



Hi Felipe, thanks for confirming this. I have used $1 to copy the file into the table. Is this ok or I am missing out on any data by doing this? Also if the file has been imported ok what do you suggest I do next to flatten the structure above? Thanks.

To get suggestions to flatten the structure: Post a new question with sample data and desired result. We'll be happy to help
